# How to guard this case

Tags: haskell

I have this function to try and "register" matches in a list of lists :

```
processMatch :: String -> POSIXTime -> [[(String, POSIXTime)]] -> [[(String, POSIXTime)]]
processMatch host time hostList =
case hostList of
  []                 -> [[(host, time)]]
  ((host, t):x):tail -> ((host, t):(host, time):x):tail
  x:t                -> x:(processMatch host time t)
```

The problem with this is that host is re-declared with a new value, instead of being a condition. So whatever host matches, I end up just adding it to the first matche's list.
I imagine I need to use a guard instead, but I can't figure out how to deconstruct my lists like that in a guard, is it even possible ?

I could just do it another way with a few conditions but I'm curious to know if it's even possible to do it simply like that.
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by defining a helper function that closes over `host` and `time`. Along side that, you can name the pair `(host, time)` as it will be used in two different places in the definition of the helper.

The helper uses a `case` expression to pattern-match only the head of an inner list, rather than trying to match the entire host list.

In the pattern that matches a host/time pair, you need to use a separate variable to capture the existing host, *then* compare that to `host` in a guard. You can only match *literals* directly in a pattern

```
processMatch :: String -> POSIXTime -> [[(String, POSIXTime)]] -> [[(String, POSIXTime)]]
processmatch host time lst = go lst
    where newPair = (host, time)
          go [] = [[newPair]]
          go (head:tail) = case head of
                            (h,t):rest | h == host ->((h,t):newPair:rest):tail
                            otherwise -> head : go tail
```

---

As an aside, a previous typo used an undefined name `first`, which came from an at-pattern in a previous version of the answer. It's probably actually worth using, but I'll mention here rather than edit the main answer:

```
first@(h,_):rest | h == host -> (first:newPair:rest):tail
```

This accomplishes two things: 1) it avoids the repetition of `(h,t)` on both sides; 2) it avoids giving a name to the matched time, which you don't really care about as long as you have `first` to refer to the pair itself.

Comment: So there is no way to both deconstruct and match variables, I thought so. That does work fine, thanks !